# reCaptcha google chrome Spring MVC double submit issue

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, recaptcha, validationerror

I am using Spring MVC 3, and JSP/JSTL for the view.  I have incorporated reCaptcha in my form.  I am noticing some very strange behaviour that is not consistent (i.e. it doesn't happen all the time, it's random) when I submit my form.  This ONLY happens with Google Chrome.

I have searched the web but was not able to find any information about this problem.

Basically, when I submit my form including a valid captcha, I am bounced back to the form page YET the captcha was VALID.  I got lucky and was able to debug it once and saw the captcha was valid, but the flow of control is somehow being intercepted DESPITE it executing the return ModelAndView logic.

So in other words, it should return a ModelAndView controller with the new view in it, but instead the flow of control goes back to the top of the function!!! and it hits the recaptcha code BUT by this time the recaptcha code is invalid, so it says FALSE. THEN it goes back to the original form page.  What is frustrating about this is there is a commit to my production database that happens because the captcha was originally valid and other valid logic that is executed as per normal behaiour.

The reCaptcha box is the only box marked with an error and it states that you must re-enter the code.  The only major issue is even if my reCaptcha was bad, it should come back immediately and say try again, which it does, but it SHOULD not appear as valid, highjack the flow of control and then redirect back to the form page.

The end result is I get 2 exact records in the database because the user submits again.  It only happens in this way.  i.e. I haven't come across a scenario when you have to submit 3 times or more.

This is ONLY happening in google Chrome.  I have tried this on firefox and IE but I have never seen this issue.  Someone in another country just submitted information via this form and I asked them what browser they were using, and they confirmed it was chrome!  I too have had enough encounters with this issue to know it actually is an issue.

Does anyone know why the flow of control goes back to the top of the function?? One other thing I noticed is the flow of control doesn't always go to the bottom, it's like it's got a mind of its own.  One other time I was stepping through and it just jumped to the top.

ANY HELP would be kindly appreciated as I am trying to figure this out in a production system!! 
Thanks!!

Comment: After a user submits the form you should always redirect and not return a new view. This will help avoid the classic double submit problem.

Comment: @Adam Gent Redirect?  I am returning a ModelAndView type with information set in it.  I only redirect when I don't return any logic to the view i.e. return new ModelAndView("redirect:/error"); SO how do I deal with this? It actually goes to the TOP of the loop in the controller post function by itself.  There was never a physical double submission.  The problem is internal.  It just goes back to the top of the method.  This ONLY happens in Chrome, not other browswer i.e. firefox or IE. which leads to believe there is something up with this chrome recaptcha combination. ANY help is appreciated.

Comment: it appears to go to the top of the method because its another request coming in (I'm assuming your using the debugger).